Jordan forms of this matrix
Suppose $n \geq 3$. Let $M \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be such that $M^3 = I_n$. What are the possible Jordan canonical forms of $M$?
This is my solution. From $M^3 = I_n$ I can deduce the minimal polynomial, $m$, divides $x^3 - 1 = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$, where $a,b,c$ are the roots of unity of $x^3 = 1$.
The minimal polynomial has only simple roots, so the all Jordan blocks will be of size 1.
So, I think these are the possiblities for the minimal polynomial and the Jordan forms:

If $m = x-a$, $x-b$ or $x-c$ then only $a$'s, $b$'s  or $c$'s in the diagonal.
If $m = (x-a)(x-b)$, then $a$'s and $b$'s in the diagonal such that $\#a$'s + $\#b$'s = $n$.
If $m = (x-a)(x-c)$, then $a$'s and $b$'s in the diagonal such that $\#a$'s + $\#c$'s = $n$.
If $m = (x-b)(x-c)$, then $a$'s and $b$'s in the diagonal such that $\#b$'s + $\#c$'s = $n$.
If $m = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$, then $a$'s and $b$'s in the diagonal such that $\#a$'s + $\#b$'s + $\#c$'s = $n$.

Is this correct?

It is correct. All cases you listed are exhaustive.
